# how do i use unique value in object overall

Tags: javascript, api, object

i have this API call, where i want to return the 3 highest and the 3 lowest "totalScore"'s in my object.

this is my function

```
app.get('/getTopThree', (req, res) => {
     let store = Store.find({}, 'name _id', function (error, response) {
     }).sort({_id:-1})
    store.then(stores => {
       let output = {}


       function delay() {
         return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           stores.map(async store => {
            var j = 0
             await Rate.find({
               "storeId": store._id
             },
             'rate date', function(error, response) {

               totalArray = [];
               response.filter(function(el) {
                 totalArray.push(el.rate);
               });
               sumOfVotes = totalArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
               totalScore = Math.round(sumOfVotes / totalArray.length * 33.33);
               var counts = {};
               for (var i = 0; i < totalArray.length; i++) {
                 var num = totalArray[i];
                 counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
               }
               var finalStore = {
                 "totalScore": totalScore
               }
               output[j++] = finalStore;
             })
           })
           setTimeout(function () {

             resolve(store)
           }, 1000)
         })
       }

       delay().then(finalStore => {
         console.log(finalStore)
         console.log(output)
         res.send({
           "store": {
             "name": finalStore,
             "score": output
           }
         })
       })
     })


   })
```

and this is my output

```
{
    "store": {
        "Klaregade": {
            "name": "Klaregade",
            "totalScore": 93
        },
        "Overgade": {
            "name": "Overgade",
            "totalScore": 67
        }
    }
}
```

So what i want is to loop though this object and return the 3 highest  as

store: { "highest": output.highest, "lowest": output.lowest" }

can anyone help me with doing that, the problem is every returned value in my object has an unique name in the start  ("klaregade" and "overgade")

how do i loop though them and take the higest and lowest value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` first on the `store` and then e.g. `array.prototype.reduce` with appropriate conditions for the lowest and highest one. What have you tried so far?

Comment: when i `object.keys(output.store) 
it gives this error  "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: And what is output when you e.g. console.log it?

Comment: `{
    "store": {
        "0": {
            "name": "Overgade",
            "totalScore": 67
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "Klaregade",
            "totalScore": 93
        }
    }
}`

i just wanna send the reponse as  e.g = 

`topThree = { "name": output.name, "totalScore": output.totalScore } `

so it returns all my objects with name and totalscore

Comment: Okay, i fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of working solution:

```
const output = {
    "store": {
        "Klaregade": {
            "name": "Klaregade",
            "totalScore": 93
        },
        "Overgade": {
            "name": "Overgade",
            "totalScore": 1
        },
        "Overgade2": {
            "name": "Overgade2",
            "totalScore": 412
        },
        "Overgade3": {
            "name": "Overgade3",
            "totalScore": 32
        },
        "Overgade4": {
            "name": "Overgade4",
            "totalScore": 67
        }
    }
}

const sorted = Object.values(output.store).sort((a, b) => b.totalScore - a.totalScore);

const store = {
  highest: sorted.slice(0, 3),
  lowest: sorted.slice(-3),
};
```

You have to keep in mind that you'll get trimmed results when `array.length < 3`

Comment: the problem my object is loaded dynamicly from database ;) so this won't be good

Comment: Ok, so please next time specify it clearly in the question, because in this statement `where i want to return the 3 highest and the 3 lowest "totalScore"'s in my object` is nothing about populating object dynamically :)
I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution for this.

what i did was instead of an object i made output to an array. and then pushed finalStore into the array.

and then in .delay.then() i made an for loop on my output

```
delay().then(finalStore => {
         console.log(output)
         for (var t = 0; t < output.length; t++) {
           output.push({
             "name": output[t].name,
             "score": output[t].totalScore
           })
         }
         res.send(output)
       })
```

like this